# Header on the top of the page on even pages

Tags: header-footer, landscape

## My question

Is it possible to print nicely the header (I use `fancyhdr`) on the top of the page on even pages (except page 1) ?

## Why do I want this?

Why so?

I have an a4 document in landscape mode and I want to staple it on the long side of the sheets, with two staples. So when the people open the document, it is natural to want the page number and other information at the top of the "inverted page".

## Edits

My footer is defined by

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{0cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{}
\lfoot{{\footnotesize EXAMPLE}}
\rfoot{{\footnotesize  \mbox{}\hfill \thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}}
```

and looks like this

[image]

I would like the "footer on the even pages" (= header actually) to look the same, with a ruler, and the page number on the top right.

Is it possible?

Comment: `\fancyhead[RE]{nicely the header}`?

Answer (score 2):

You can play around with the orientation of the placement, depending on the side that you're stapling together:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper = a4paper,
  landscape,
  twoside
}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Default
\fancyhead[LO]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}% Page number on Left on an Odd page
\fancyhead[RE]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\rotatebox{-90}{\thepage}}}% Page numebr on Right on an Even page

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but my header is more complicated and I don't know how to handle it. Can you help me? I will edit the question to give more details. Thanks

Comment: @Colas: Sure. Your update now talks about the footer on odd pages, while the title requests help with the even header. Please clarify what you're after. Make it easier for us to understand...

Comment: Yep, I'm sorry. I made a mistake. It is at the top on the even pages and at the bottom on odd pages. I will re-edit my question. Thanks 

Comment: @Colas: Try [this paste](https://pastebin.com/zq83mZzF). Let me know what needs to change, if anything.

Comment: Yep it works but on the odd pages, I would like to have no header (ie no space and no rule), and on even pages to have no footer (ie no space and no rule).

Comment: Did you see my last comment? Thanks

Comment: @Colas: Yes. I'll look at this later today.